# Interactive game: there is an error in the following code Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `;' or `}'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Help Required: I wanted to compare two InputFields 1 which is displaying a number and 1 where the user can input an alphabet that will compare to the display and then the display field will change the color to green on right input and red on the wrong input. numEnemies shows an unexpected symbol and by using I <= 3 asking for parsing int to bool

```
public void InputCheking()
{
    UserInput = inp2.text;  // input field to get input from the user
    for(int i = 0; i &lt; numEnemies; i++)
    {
        switch (UserInput) 
        {
        case "H":
            CheckingForEight();
            break;
        case "U":
            CheckingForTwentyOne();
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log("Default execute");
            inp2.text = "";
            break;
        }
        Debug.Log("Creating enemy number: " + i);
    }
}

public void CheckingForEight()
{
    //========================Taking Static
    Debug.Log(inp1.text); // inp1 is an input field showing a perticular number gainst Alphabet such as 1 for A, 2 for B, and so on and so forth 
    if (UserInput == "H")
    {
        Debug.Log ("1st Phase");
        inp1.text = "H";
        inp1.image.color = Color.green; 
        inp2.text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        inp1.text = "8";
        Debug.Log("2nd Phase");
        inp1.image.color = Color.red;
    }

}
public void CheckingForTwentyOne()
{
    //========================Taking Static
    Debug.Log(inp1.text);
    UserInput = inp2.text;
    if (UserInput == "U")
    {
        inp21.text = "U";// another input field that shows 21 against alphabet U
        inp21.image.color = Color.green; 

    }
    else
    {
        inp21.text = "21";
        Debug.Log("Input In 2nd Phase");
        inp21.image.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: unity showing me "Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `;' or `}'"

Comment: @TehminaAslam add that detail to the question, include the line that its throwing the error on

Comment: Bad copy and paste is the issue with your code. `&lt` should be `<` if you want that to compile

Comment: @Programmer you forget the `;`, OP must replace `&lt;`

Comment: ; (semi colon) already there

Answer (score 0):

> Finally Working .....

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;




public class Level_1 : MonoBehaviour {

string word = null;
int wordIndex = 0;
string alpha;
public InputField textBox = null;
[SerializeField] private float mainTimer;
public Text timerText; 
public static float timer = 20f;
public Text resultText;

private bool canCounter = true;
private bool doOnce = false;

public InputField display8;
public InputField display21;
public InputField display12;
public InputField display11;
public InputField userInputField;

public string userEntry;




public void keyboardFunction(string alphabet){

    wordIndex++;
    word = word + alphabet;
    textBox.text = word; 
}

public void Okay()
{
    InputCheking ();
}
public void ValueChangeCheck()
{
    Debug.Log("Value Changed");
}
void Start () {
    timer = mainTimer; 

    //numStart = (int)KeyCode.Alpha0;
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void Update () {
    if (timer >= 0.0f && canCounter) {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = timer.ToString("F");
    }
    else if (timer <= 0.0f && !doOnce){

        canCounter = false;
        doOnce = true;
        timerText.text = "0.00";
        timer = 0.0f; 
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("ResultScreen", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
    //  Debug.Log ("Scene Lodaing after TimeUp!");




}
public void InputCheking()
{
    userEntry = userInputField.text;
    switch (userEntry) 
    {
    case "H":
        Debug.Log ("User put H");
        display8.image.color = Color.green;
        display8.text = "H";
        userInputField.image.color = Color.white;
        display8.DeactivateInputField ();
        userInputField.text = "";
        break;
    case "U":
        Debug.Log ("User put U");
        display21.text = "U";
        display21.image.color = Color.green;
        userInputField.image.color = Color.white;
        userInputField.text = "";
        break;
    case "L":
        Debug.Log ("User put L");
        display12.text = "L";
        display12.image.color = Color.green;
        userInputField.image.color = Color.white;
        userInputField.text = "";
        break;
    case "K":
        display11.image.color = Color.green;
        display11.text = "K";
        userInputField.image.color = Color.white;
        userInputField.text = "";
        Result ();
        Debug.Log ("User put K");
        break;
    default:

        Debug.Log ("Please Enter a correct Alphabet against Number");
        userInputField.image.color = Color.red;
        userInputField.text = "TRY AGAIN";
        break;
    }
}
public void Result()
{
    if (display8.text == "H" && display21.text == "U" && display12.text == "L" && display11.text == "K") {
    //  DisplayComment.text = "Excellent";
        Debug.Log ("Working");
    } 
    else 
    {
        userInputField.text = "Complete All Boxes";
    }
}
```

}